# Windows not showing up in grub menu

Tags: linux, grub

I had Arch Linux installed, but for some reason the partition where the OS was, got deleted. I also had Windows 7 Ultimate on another partition and the GRUB menu use to show it. After my Arch install was deleted, I installed Linux Mint Cinnamon 18. And since then my Windows 7 Ultimate is not showing up GRUB menu. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Give [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) a try. I had similar problems in the past and resolved it with Boot-Repair.

Start up Mint

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Then follow the recommended instructions from the above link.